# Severity Notice: Code Igniter

Tags: php

```
public function adduser()
{

    $this->load->model('User', 'user');
    $this->user->adduser(); 
    $data = array('message' => 'Thanks for signing up');
    $this->load->view('register', $data);
}
```

This is my function and it executes perfectly and gives a message of thanks to the register view page. But when I am loading the register view page initially, it gives me an error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: message
Filename: views/register.php
Line Number: 15
```

if anyone can help where it is going wrong.

Comment: <?php echo $message; ?>

Comment: okay, you're printing something that initially is not set =) You can do some workaround

Comment: ya i want to print success data in code igniter

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regard to the comment section mentioned workaround is

```
<?php echo ((isset($message)) ? $message : '');?>
```

Please see [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: ya this solved it, the isset function removes the error. Thank you guys.